# JCR-SQL2 Query Subnodes

Tags: sql, jcr, magnolia, jcr-sql2

I need to find an entry in the JCR where a Date in a list of nodes containing dates matches my criteria.
Data Structure is

`- Event1
-- Dates
--- 0
---- startDate: xyz
---- endDate: xyz
--- 1
---- startDate: xyz
---- endDate: xyz
- Event1
-- Dates
--- 0
---- startDate: xyz
---- endDate: xyz
--- 1
---- startDate: xyz
---- endDate: xyz`

[image: Data Structure]

So I need iterate over all Nodes and now I need to select the subnode called `DATE` and iterate over that and check the timestamp prop. If the timestamp matches my criterium, then return the whole node.

here's a failed attempt:

`select p.date from [mgnl:contact] as p where p.[startDate] > CAST('2010-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00' as date)`

which i was hoping to fetch me all entries after jan 1. 2010.

I could do this by just grabbing everything from the jcr and doing this filtering in Java. In JCR-SQL2, I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it doesn't work because p.date is not direct property of the given node type. I assume it'd work if you change it to `mgnl:contentNode`.

Also give this a shot:

`select * from [mgnl:contact] where [startDate] > cast('2010-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00' as date)`

Cheers,

HTH,

Comment: thank you! both answers sadly give back empty results. I guess the problem is, that [startDate] is a child of an unnamed (numbered) node which is in turn a child of a node called [date]. I don't understand how I can query the child props of a list of such unnamed nodes. The way you wrote your queries, it seems I can just ignore the path of the nodes? thanks again!

Comment: seems I misunderstood before. playing around with it it's solved and you were absolutely right in your comment. thank you!